# How to add extra custom content type to Contacts based ListInstance

Tags: 2010, content-type, custom-list

I am trying to build a custom ListInstance for deployment in Visual Studio. It should be based on the Contacts template so it can be opened in/linked to Outlook, but I also want to add two other custom content types to the ListInstance. How do I do that?

It is possible to create what I want through the web interface, but I would like to do it in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried exporting the site where you have created the lists as a WSP and imported the project in Visual Studio?

List instances in SP2010 use the CustomSchema attribute in Elements schema. Exporting the list should give you the Schema.xml for the list instance